# Accessibility voice-over support for different languages which doesn't support in iOS by default?

Tags: ios, localization, accessibility, voiceover

I'm developing iOS application for the blind people. In the beginning of the application user can select his/her preferred language and according to that app's contents(text) will change to selected language.
App support users who are understand English and Tamil.

I don't have any issues if user selected "English" as proffered language, but I need to know how can I convert "Tamil to Speech" voice over in iOS? ( basically a language doesn't support by default in voice over)

Is there another way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Why aren't you allowing the iOS device language localization to do this for you?  Why is this a decision they make in your app?

Comment: I used language localization to change text content in the app, but can we change speech voice over when user choose different language. For an example say English word "enter" changed into "உள்ளிடவும்" when user changed the language to the tamil. Will it read/speech in native tamil language when user double tap on it? This decision made since there are  people who cant understand English and app used by within one country.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution for this? Tamil is still not supported by Voice over, is it possible to make voice over read languages that it doesn't support?